# Unable to Redirect to any asp pages under Account folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have three content pages - `Login.aspx, Logout.aspx, MyAccount.aspx`. All three are under the same folder-`Account`
All three pages are part of a Content site referencing the same master page.

Now the Master page has `Logout` and `MyAccount` hyperlinks.
When I click these link I am redirected to `Login.aspx`. Now I dont understand why this is happening.
Actually even if I type `~/Account/MyAccount.aspx` in the browser I am redirected to `~/Account/Login.aspx`
Further if I try to redirect to any page under `Account` folder I am redirected to `Login.aspx` page.

Am I missing something?  Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be under Account, the Login.aspx is set to startup object???

Comment: it might be because you might have kept the session check on page load of master page so it redirect you back to login page. How are you checking your session and where are you storing it.?

Comment: @SaiKalyanAkshinthala : how do i check startup object in Account folder in Visual web developer express 2010

Comment: you can check in Web.config.its default page set Login.aspx in Authentication.which below i point it out.try to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config you specifie your login methode and also there the site redirects if the user isn´t logedin & trys to open a site without priviliges:

```
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" ... />
```

If you want that every user has access to some ressources you have to specifie them:

```
<location path="Content">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

and finaly only allow authorized users access to the rest:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
  ...
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's checking user credentials?

Comment: but i can redirect to any page like - `Home.aspx or About.aspx`, only cant redirect to pages inside Account folder

Answer (score 0):

Remove or Comment deny users tag in Account's Web Config

```
<authorization>
  <!--<deny users="?"/>-->
</authorization>
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874357/web-config-authorization-deny-unauthorised) getting understand. further [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719554%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: well in this situation how will i login.. bcoz Login.aspx will never be shown